laptop keyboard, but not touch-pad, disabled after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04
Upgrading Ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04 was painful in more than one way, but the most critical issue is that sometimes I lose responsiveness from the laptop keyboard. This is grave since I cannot use my computer on the train or sofa. I am not sure about what triggers this. Perhaps shutting the lid while USB keyboard is connected and open it with no external keyboard. The problem resolved itself a few times and returned, but I don't know what I did to make it go away. I opened gnome-tweaks, I installed some libraries, in any case it is back and I have no laptop keyboard. The issue is different than described in other messages by:

I lose keyboard only, not the touchpad
The Fn key works in combination with function buttons (flight mode, keyboard illumination)
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks


Since wayland and XServer differ : could you change your session from wayland (the default)  to "XServer" and check if the problem persists?

My default is xorg. I also tried wayland and even installed mate, no response.
Moreover, I tried starting the laptop from an external drive (debian 12) but it gave the same results

Question is now, what kind of hardware do you use. There are some laptops that have queer drivers  - yours might not be supported by the current kernels. You might find some drivers for the keyboard. To prevent any hassle - use a Thinkpad. My old Thinkkpad R61i (20 years old) runs with the latest kernel...

The problem is gone now, this is frustrating. I changed nothing. I connected to a TV screen where the problem last occurred, and to my surprise the keyboard responded.
